# jpa doesn't see table in db

Tags: database, jpa, jakarta-ee, database-connection, jpql

When I execute

*@NamedQuery(name = "GroupsHasStudent.findByGroupsidGroups", query = "SELECT g FROM GroupsHasStudent g WHERE g.groupsHasStudentPK.groupsidGroups = :groupsidGroups"),*

of *GroupsHasStudent* entity, the result is generated correct. But another NativeQuery

```
getEntityManager().
            createNativeQuery(
            "SELECT d.idDiscipline, d.name, gy.idGroupsYear, gy.year, g.idGroups "
            + "FROM Discipline d, Groupsyear gy, Groups g, GroupsHasStudent ghs "
            + "WHERE ghs.groupsHasStudentPK.groupsidGroups=2").
            getResultList();
```

throws the Exception

```
Internal Exception:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
Table 'mydb.groupshasstudent' doesn't exist
```

Actually I do don't have such table in db, but the correct name is *groups_has_student* which is specified in @Table:

(My entity:)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups_has_student")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "GroupsHasStudent.findAll", query = "SELECT g FROM GroupsHasStudent g"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "GroupsHasStudent.findByGroupsidGroups", query = "SELECT g FROM GroupsHasStudent g WHERE g.groupsHasStudentPK.groupsidGroups = :groupsidGroups"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "GroupsHasStudent.findByStudentUserslogin", query = "SELECT g FROM GroupsHasStudent g WHERE g.groupsHasStudentPK.studentUserslogin = :studentUserslogin")})
public class GroupsHasStudent implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected GroupsHasStudentPK groupsHasStudentPK;

    public GroupsHasStudent() {
    }
```

And even when I rename table in mysql to *groupshasstudent* there is another Exception

```
Unknown column 'ghs.groupsHasStudentPK.studentUserslogin' in 'where clause'
```

І це сумно..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a native (SQL) query, it's a JPQL query, therefore you should use `createQuery()` instead of `createNativeQuery()`.